# Plotting coordinate data on a torus in R

Tags: r, plot

I'm importing coordinate data from a model (NetLogo) and am trying to plot it in R. In the NetLogo model the size of the area is given as a 221 x 221 torus with maximum x and y values of 110 and minimum x and y values also of 110.

My code to plot the data, grid the area and extract the number of points per patch is as follows:

```
x<-c(1:50)
y<-c(1:50)

plot(x, y, pch = 16, xlim=c(-110,110), ylim=c(-110,110))

grid(110,110,lty=1)

xt<-cut(x,seq(-110,110,1))
yt<-cut(y,seq(-110,110,1))

count<-as.vector(table(xt,yt))
table(count)
```

But when I do this it's obviously giving me the number of patches as 48400. How do I properly set the values so it's 48841 (i.e. 221 x 221)?

Comment: can you add data for x and y. This is not a reproducible example as it stands.

Comment: @dww I've added x and y data now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-2,  -1,   0,  1,  2
5 objects mean 4 intervals, so the plot has (221 - 1)^ 2 patches.